# Objective-C how to call functions in original view controller from NSObjects

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that connects to a web service. The actual call i have put into a NSObject simply because i have several points on different screens where i connect to a web service.

So my NSObject file looks like the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSURL_Layer : NSObject
+ (NSArray*) GetProductIdentifiers;
+ (NSArray*) ReturnArray:(NSData*)json;
@end





#import "NSURL Layer.h"

@implementation NSURL_Layer
+ (NSArray*) GetProductIdentifiers : (void*) function
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* kivaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"blah blah"]
                        ];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            function:[self ReturnArray: kivaData];
        });    
    });
    return NULL;
}

+ (NSArray*) ReturnArray:(NSData*)json{
    //Convert data here from json to nsarray
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];

    return jsonArray;
}
@end
```

My issue is how do i call a function in my original view controller from the function ReturnArray? For example update a tableview? Or is the best way to have ReturnArray a function in the view controller and somehow call that function from the code block in the URL call?

Thanks

Comment: Just so you know convention says your method names should start with lower case letters so should be `+ (NSArray*)productIdentifiers;` and `+ (NSArray*)returnArray:(NSData*)json;` also note the removal of the `get` objective-c doesn't generally use `get`. Not saying you should never use `get` but under this situation you don't need to use it. And finally why do you declare the method like `+ (NSArray*) GetProductIdentifiers;` in the interface file but then in the implementation have `+ (NSArray*) GetProductIdentifiers : (void*) function` note the extra `:(void*)function`?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this case is completion block, you could use it like this:

```
+ (void)getProductIdentifiers:(void (^)(NSArray*, NSError*))completionBlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* kivaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"blah blah"]
                        ];

        NSArray* array = ... // parse JSON, still in background queue
        NSError* error = ... // get error if there's any
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(array, error);
        });    
    });
}
```

You use it like this:

```
[NSURL_Layer getProductIdentifiers: ^void (NSArray* array, NSError* error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        // use array
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Note some differences here:

- You are making a synchronous web call in a background queue, that's ok, but you're parsing JSON in a main queue - that's not good and could be also performed in a background queue (which you could see in my code example).
- I've replaced function with a block as it's more convenient and suitable in Objective-C world.
- Your functions should not return anything, because all the processing is performed asynchronously and they return immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Try to send notification to another class with `NSNotificationCenter`:

You must first register a notification name in original view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTableView:) name:@"UpdateTableView" object:nil];
```

And then post a notification with a dictionary of parameters

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateTableView" object: jsonArray userInfo:nil];
```